# Unique values from a list of integers in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a pandas column,

[image]

I want only unique list of values where values don't repeat after appearing once.

Resulting column will only contain following rows,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to filter any number that has already appeared in the DataFrame.

You would need to maintain visited/appeared numbers at a global level.

Then add numbers to appeared set in  `detectDupliate` function

```
appeared = set() 
def detectDuplicate(row):
    for i in row:
        if i in appeared:
            return True
        appeared.add(i)
    return False




df = pd.DataFrame({"array": [[11, 314, 188], [1,636,189], [1,636, 190], [1,637, 189]]})
df["isDuplicate"] = df["array"].apply(lambda x: detectDuplicate(x))


df = df[df.isDuplicate == False]
```

Output:

```
    array   isDuplicate
0   [11, 314, 188]  False
1   [1, 636, 189]   False
```

Comment: okay but 1 and 2 are still appearing in second tuple, it must not return those repeating values.